# How to share constantly changing variables between two python scripts?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and got stocked when trying to define a shared variable between two scripts such that any value changes of the shared variable in the parent script will immediately 'sync' to the child script.

For example:

1. Every two seconds, `Parent.py` inputs value 1 to 3 to the shared variable A, **one at a time**.
2. `Child.py` keeps waiting for the value changes of A and printing them out.

so we should get something like:

```
1

...(2 seconds past)

2

...(2 seconds past)

3
```

That is just an example. My actual scripts are more complicated and need to run concurrently so I am thinking about using `multiprocessing.pipe` or `multiprocessing.queue`  but not sure which one to choose and how to add it into my scripts. I will be greatly appreciated if someone could help me out:)

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use threads or ordinary `multiprocessing`?

Comment: You have examples of processes exchanging information in multiprocessing.py, in section 16.6.1.2 http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Yes I have looked over that section, but not clear how to add it into my two scripts. should I write a third script just for multiprocessing ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()`. The parent pushes to the queue, and the child pops. The Manager seems like an unecessary intermediate step, since there's a multiprocessing.Queue, but the implementation is much simpler and less prone to deadlocks and other bugs.

http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Queue